# NullPointer with BufferedReader and split()

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader

I am tring to read a file which has lines like so:

```
438782    Abaca bunchy top virus    NC_010314    Musa Sp.
```

So the lines contain information seperated by tabs. I am tring to read this file and do something with every line after splitting them. It keeps throwing a `NullPointerException` error though. This always happens on the line where I try to split. In the code below I left everything unrelated to this issue out.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
String nextLine = br.readLine();
String[] line;
while (nextLine != null) {
    nextLine = br.readLine();
    line = nextLine.split("\t"); //Error line
    //Do something with line
}
```

Comment: Obviously, nextLine is null. Do a null check first. Also split on `\\t`.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas If I don't try to split it, I can work with nextLine just fine.

Comment: @RnRoger No you can't. It's null. There is no line to work with. The standard way to write this loop is `while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)`. Then you cannot possibly get a `NullPointerException` inside the `while` block.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: What the heck, [the post that you just answered was deleted by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604436/else-if-statements-not-running-through-all-possibilities). I thank you for your efforts, but it looks like the OP just wanted to waste your time.

Answer (score 1):

This line should be the last one inside your while loop, not the first

```
nextLine = br.readLine();
```