# Else if statements not running through all possibilities

Tags: java

```
    if (condition1){//checks intersect
        if(condition2){//checks A
            if(condition3){
                System.out.println("Collision A");
            }   
        }else if(condition4){
            if(condition5){
                System.out.println("Collision B");
            }
        }else if(condition6){
            System.out.println("Collision C");
        }else{  
            System.out.println("Collision D");
        }
        System.out.println("Collision done");
    }
```

When I run this code in a method, Collision D never works/prints. However collision done always prints. So normally the cmd prints "Collision A Collision done" but when collision d happens it only prints "collision done."

Edit: heavily simplified the code, the conditions themselves aren't the issues.

Comment: That code should be taken out back and shot. No mercy.

Comment: Seriously, how can you debug that mess? Refactor, simplify, use methods where needed, but please for your sake and ours, clean up that mess.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Shootin' is too good for this code. Get a spoon, a lemon and a cheese grater.

Comment: Don't worry about the messiness, I'm just confused why when the Collision C if statement returns false the collision d code doesn't run.

Comment: Even just adding a space here or there, while syntactically unnecessary, would go a long way to make the code more readable. No reason to cram code into as small a space as possible. The days of 80 column displays is long past. The point of fixing your messiness is so that we can help you. Remember, you're the one asking for help here, and I, for one, won't walk into a room stacked ankle high in turd.

Comment: `"Don't worry about the messiness..."` -- how can you say that when you ask volunteers to read and understand this crap and then help you? Seriously, the messiness *matters*.

Comment: The only way to *only* print "Collision done" is if only the outer-if of 'colision a' triggers. You never actually trigger the 'D' use case. Put an else after the "Collision A" `if` and you'll see *that's* what's triggering.

Comment: Please look again i have simplified it

Comment: What your describing would happen if condition2 were true and condition3 false.  Or if condition4 were true and condition5 false.  Since I didn't study your code before the edit (and I don't really want to), I can't tell whether those are realistic scenarios or not.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, ignoring the mess of variables, you have this set up:

```
 if (condition1){//checks intersect
    if(condition2){//checks A
        if(condition3){
            System.out.println("Collision A");
        }   
    }else if(condition4){
        if(condition5){
            System.out.println("Collision B");
        }
    }else if(condition6){
        System.out.println("Collision C");
    }else{  
        System.out.println("Collision D");
    }
    System.out.println("Collision done");
}
```

The *only* way to only print the "Collision Done" message and none of the other "Collision A-D" messages, is if you trigger conditions 1, 2, and *not* 3, or if you trigger conditions 1, 4, and *not* 5. You are not triggering the "Collision D" use case; your "Collision A" and "Collision B" use cases are incomplete.

If you want to trigger "Collision D" in this case, you need to change the `if(condition 2)` to instead be `if(condition2 && !condition3 && !condition4 && !condition6)`; or f you're falling through the 'condition4' case,you'll need to change the `if(condition4)` to instead be `if(condition4 && !condition5 && !condition6)`.

Or, alternatively, change your structure to be more like:

```
 if (condition1){//checks intersect
    if(condition2 && condition3){
        System.out.println("Collision A");            
    }else if(condition4 && condition5){
        System.out.println("Collision B");
    }else if(condition6){
        System.out.println("Collision C");
    }else{  
        System.out.println("Collision D");
    }
    System.out.println("Collision done");
}
```

Given the complexity of your original code, and the vagueness of the updated code, it's hard to determine which is more appropriate in your particular case.

Comment: Yay, we geot this re-opened. 1+